# Is it possible to create a dictionary inside a function using python?

Tags: python

I am trying the following

```
def myfunction(list_a, list_b, my_dict):
   dict1 = dict(zip(list_a, list_b))
   my_dict = copy.deepcopy(dict1)
```

but when I call myfunction I get an emtpty dictionary...

Comment: Is it expected to return a value?

Comment: you need a `return`.

Comment: Are you calling this function, and expecting the reference you used as the argument `my_dict` to contain the copy? If so, it will not. Parameters are passed by the value of the object reference

Comment: @ Jonathan Clede I need the dictionary that is supposed to be produced by this function

Comment: @James Wierzba you are right! I am quite new to programming.. I had an idea that as I can pass an empty list inside a function and append it that I could do something similar with a dictionary like pass an empty dictionary and fill it somehow inside a function.. thank you for your theoretical support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def myfunction(list_a, list_b):
   dict1 = dict(zip(list_a, list_b))
   return copy.deepcopy(dict1)

my_dict = myfunction(some_list_a, some_list_b)
```

as MaxNoe noticed - deepcopy is not needed

```
def myfunction(list_a, list_b):
   return dict(zip(list_a, list_b))

my_dict = myfunction(some_list_a, some_list_b)
```

or even

```
my_dict = dict(zip(some_list_a, some_list_b))
```

Comment: Why would you make a deep copy of an object you just created?

Comment: thank you! but how can I then have access to the returned dictionary? How do I refer to it?

Comment: `my_dict[some_key]`, `my_dict[other_key]`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it a function, you should just simply return the dict. No need to give an dictionary or make a `deepcopy`:

```
def dict_from_lists(keys, vals):
    return dict(zip(keys, vals))

my_dict = dict_from_lists(list_a, list_b)
```

But for one line of code only using builtins, I would normally not write a function.

In my opinion

```
my_dict = dict(zip(list_a, list_b))
```

is pythonic, it does not need a user function that hides what is going on.

Comment: I need to make it a lot of times for different lists so I thought to try make a fuction to do it for me for all the times needed

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by value of the reference, so assigning a new value to the parameter within the function will not change the value of the object reference that was passed to it.

I suggest returning the copy instead.

```
def myfunction(list_a, list_b):
   dict1 = dict(zip(list_a, list_b))
   return copy.deepcopy(dict1)
```